# Est-il possible de commencer une phrase par un gérondif

Tags: grammaire, gérondif

Est-il possible de commencer une phrase par un gérondif ?

Par exemple,

> « En lisant, en regardant la fusée dessinée au plafond, elle s'est aussi endormie en remerciant Dieu pour cette belle vie.»

Si ce n'est pas possible, pourriez-vous le corriger s'il vous plaît ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, on peut commencer une phrase par un gérondif :

> [En passant par la Lorraine avec mes sabots [...]](https://youtu.be/lxRQ-1QJfTU)

Il y a un petit problème potentiel avec la phrase proposée, *lire* et *regarder une fusée au plafond* ne peuvent pas être simultanés. On pourrait écrire:

> En lisant son livre puis en regardant la fusée dessinée au plafond, elle s'endormit en remerciant Dieu pour cette belle vie.